# Using firestore document snapshot listener for local print

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a cloud based billing system with automatic printing when firestore document created. For that I have created c# console application with listening to filtered collection with outlet and timestamp when listener is started.

To overcome getting all documents since timestamp, I am adding one more parameter "is_printed" as bool and updating document with "is_printed" as true. So next time all documents which has "is_printed" true will be excluded from collection.

Am I having right approach or there is something else that I can evaluate as best fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a boolean field to mark a document as processed is good enough to fit your current requirement. But you might want to add another field `status` which can be marked according to the processing status of the document.

This might come in handy if in case a new requirement arises to list all the documents according to its print status.

For example:

1) Documents which are in **PENDING** (Newly created ones).

2) Documents which are in **INPROGRESS** state.

3) Documents which are in **FAILED** state.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I am predicting more than 5000 active listeners in next 1 year. I hope this works . However I am aware that every change there will be hit on billing for document snapshot read. Later on will figure out best alternative approach from AWS SQS / MQTT etc.